# two if conditions in for loop bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell-script

I've trying to make two if conditions in for loop. Is it possible this? Now doesn't return anything from second `if` only two `OK` from first `if`.

```
#!/bin/bash
servers=("212.39.82.157" "212.39.82.157" "1.1.1.1")

for i in "${servers[@]}"; do

ping -c 1 $i > /dev/null 
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "OK"  
  fi

  if [ $(netstat -na | grep ':3708' | grep ESTABLISH | wc -l) -eq 2 ]; then
     echo "NOT - OK"
  fi
done
```

For third `IP`in the list must return `NOT - OK` since is not online. But the output is this

```
root@ubuntu:~$ ./check.sh
OK
OK
root@ubuntu:~$
```

What I missing here?

UPDATE:

```
 #!/bin/bash
servers=("212.39.82.157" "212.39.82.157" "1.1.1.1")

for i in "${servers[@]}"; do

ping -c 1 $i > /dev/null 
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "OK"  
  fi
done
  if [ $(netstat -na | grep ':3708' | grep ESTABLISH | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "NOT - OK"
  fi
```

If I put it outside for loop it must work?

Comment: What does running that `netstat` command output? You can have as many `if`s as you want inside a loop.

Comment: Whats the output of `$(netstat -na | grep ':3708' | grep ESTABLISH | wc -l)` within the script ? Is it only 2 lines  ? I would echo it out to double check whether it's 2 lines or not. If it's not 2 lines, then you won't get a `NOT - OK` response.

Comment: @Lawrence, yes is two lines. I don't think that `netstat` return 2 linest now on this PC. So the condition is ok and if `netstat` return two lines should work?

Comment: Do you want to use the server ip $i somewhere in that grep command? Without using $i, the netstat|grep|grep|wc command will always output the same thing.

Comment: Your netstat line does not use the `$i` value at all. So either you'll get the "NOT - OK" line three times, or not at all.

Comment: Clearly is my mistake. I must execute second condition outside ping loop. How can I make it outside?

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put hosts, IP addresses in a file for example.

`hosts.txt` contains the following

```
212.39.82.157 
212.39.82.155 
1.1.1.1
22.22.22.22
```

Create the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

ping_hosts(){
echo
echo "*** Ping all hosts ***"
echo "--------------------------------------------"

count1=0
count2=0
start=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y-%T")

hosts=( 1.1.1.1 2.3.3.4 4.5.6.6 )

while read -r line
do
#PING=`ping -s 64 $line -c 1 | grep packet | awk '{print $(NF-2)}'`
PING=$(ping -s 64 $line -c 1 | grep packet | awk '{print $(NF-4)}')

if [[ "$PING" == "0%" ]]; then
count1=$((count1 + 1))
printf '%s\n' "$line UP" 
else
count2=$((count2 + 1))
printf '%s\n\n' "$line DOWN"
fi
done < <( printf '%s\n' "${hosts[@]}")

end=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y-%T")

printf '%s\n' "Start:$start"
printf '%s\n\n' "End**:$end"
printf '%s\n' "$count1 hosts UP and $count2 hosts down"

}
ping_hosts
```

Now make the script executable and run it. Probably it defeats the purpose for what you want. Just wanted to share it.

**UPDATE your answer**

```
#!/bin/bash
servers=("212.39.82.157" "212.39.82.157" "1.1.1.1")

for i in "${servers[@]}"; do

ping -c 1 $i > /dev/null 
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "OK"  
  elif [ $(netstat -na | grep ':3708' | grep ESTABLISH | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "NOT - OK"
  fi
done
```

As a side note, your script is poorly written when it comes to bash syntax.

Comment: I'm a bit new in bash scripting and I don't understand this quite well. Can I not use second file for hosts?

Comment: @IvanPetrov What do you mean with a second file?  You mean have hosts in two seperate files or..?

Comment: Yes, I want to have hosts in the same file.

Comment: @IvanPetrov see my updated answer. You can put hosts in an array variable and then read from the array just like you'd read from a file.

Comment: I've also updated my question. Can you check it? Note: My script is working fine. I just need to add second if.

Comment: @IvanPetrov see update.

Comment: But in this case it will not perform second case untill the first doesn't fail. Right? I need always to perform both condition..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16099/discussion-between-val0x00ff-and-ivan-petrov).