# Add date output before command output to beginning of file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am trying to find a way to include the date to a log just before the command is output to the file.
Here is what I am trying to do. I have this in a shell script that runs every 5 minutes via crontab.

```
ping -c5 -q ipaddress > log.log
```

However, I would like a date stamp just before that output in the log. I've tried this:

```
date && ping -c5 -q ipaddress > log.log
```

But that doesn't seem to work.
Thanks.

Comment: What output do you want? Please [edit] your question and show us the _exact_ output you would like to see. Should the date be on every line? Some of them? Just once for each time `ping` runs?

Comment: Yep. That works also. Thanks.
There's always more than one way to do something in Linux, and that is why I love it.

Comment: @t3kg33k  also see an example here:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147612/two-if-conditions-in-for-loop-bash-scripting/147614#147614

Answer (score 0):

So, whomever posted the answer I was looking for deleted it. Here is what they posted and worked for me:

```
printf '[%s] %s\n' "$(date)" "$(ping -c5 -q ipaddress)" > log.log
```